# Could not locate shadow view with tag #1724133, this is probably caused by a temporary inconsistency between native views and shadow views

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native 0.63, have this message in my console.

```
Could not locate shadow view with tag #1724133, this is probably caused by a temporary inconsistency between native views and shadow views.
```

I don't know why and how to fix it, it appears after I launch an action on my view, and my page is very slow for several seconds after that.

If you have any ideas I would be delighted